# why isn't rsync copying files to the server

Tags: rsync

I'm following along with a Railscast that teaches how to set up Chef solo. It uses two interesting terminal commands that I had never seen before, only one of which I can get to work. When I do

```
scp -r root@198.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/chef .
```

It copies the contents of the remote server directory to my local machine. The following command is supposed to sync the files back to the server after I change them on my machine

```
rsync -r . root@198.XXX.XXX.XXX:/var/chef
```

However, the changes aren't showing on the remote server, and when I run the chef commands that are supposed to apply the changes, it's not showing any changes that need to be made.

Am I using rsync incorrectly?

Update

Running this command gave the following output. Still no changes are shown on the remote server

```
rsync -rvv . root@198.XXX.XXX.XXX:/var/chef


`building file list ... 
done
delta-transmission enabled
chef/node.json
chef/solo.rb
chef/cache/chef-client-running.pid
chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
chef/chef/node.json
chef/chef/solo.rb
chef/chef/cache/chef-client-running.pid
chef/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
chef/chef/cookbooks/main/recipes/default.rb
chef/cookbooks/main/recipes/default.rb
chef/cookbooks/main/templates/default/zshrc.erb
total: matches=17  hash_hits=17  false_alarms=0 data=0
sent 1167 bytes  received 442 bytes  643.60 bytes/sec
total size is 6236  speedup is 3.88`
```

Update

You'll notice from the above update that a `templates` directory should be inside the `main` directory (along with a `recipes` directory), however, this is what's showing

```
root@Chef3:/var/chef/cookbooks# cd main
root@Chef3:/var/chef/cookbooks/main# ls
recipes
```

Comment: What's the output of `rsync -rv . root@198.XXX.XXX.XXX:/var/chef`? You are indeed using rsync incorrectly (not your fault, looks like a bad tutorial), but not in a way that should cause the changed files not to be transferred.

Comment: Thanks, It says, "building file list ... done" and then it lists the files. However, they still haven't been copied to the remote server (at least the changes aren't apparent on the remote server)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `rsync -rvv …` (`-v` tells rsync to report each file that it copies; doubling the `-v` option tells rsync to also say why it skips a file)

Comment: Thanks, it's not reporting why it's skipping any of the files. I'll post the output in an update to the OP.

Comment: Please run the command `df -h /var` and also what does the output of `ls -ld /var` look like? Also can you provide a link to the screencast?

Comment: Is that the list of all the files in the directory? If not, which ones are missing? Are you sure the edited files aren't being transmitted?

Comment: `ls -l /var/chef` too.

Comment: I have my money on 1 of 2 things: no diskspace to write files or the files are there.

Comment: @sim how do I check for diskspace? I'll update the OP to show you what's inside the main folder. You'll notice from the rsync update that a templates folder should have been transferred but it's not there.

Comment: @Gilles the whole template directory inside the main directory is missing. There were updates to node.json file that aren't showing, as well as updates to default.rb file not showing on the server

Comment: Thanks, there is diskspace (18G), and the files still aren't there `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda         20G  1.2G   18G   6% /`   Incidentally, although 18G is plenty of space, I'm surprised that 2G has already been used as I've only installed Chef and Ruby on it

Comment: @Leahcim Are there symbolic links involved? Please post the output of `ls -ld * chef/node.json`. Is it normal that you have a `chef directory inside the `chef` directory | could that be causing the confusion?

Comment: @gilles yes, that's the problem. The transferred files are inside the chef directory inside the chef directory. Thanks

Comment: I use `rsync -av` instead of `rsync -r`.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two file hierarchies mixed up: `/var/chef` and `/var/chef/chef`. It looks like you're editing one and then reading back the other.

`scp -r root@198.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/chef .` creates a `chef` directory inside the current directory. If you ran that from `/var/chef`.

---

The proposed commands are terrible. Forget everything you read in that tutorial.

`scp -r` does not preserve file permissions or times. Use `scp -rp` to preserve them.

`rsync -r` does not preserve file permissions or times. Forget that the `-r` option exists. Use `rsync -a` instead, which preserves all usual metadata. Always pass the `-a` option to rsync unless you have a good reason not to.

When you write `rsync -a /path/to/source /path/to/destination`, this creates a subdirectory called `source` under `destination`. If you want to synchronize `/path/to/source` with `/path/to/destination` instead, add a final `/` at the end of the destination: `rsync -a /path/to/source /path/to/destination/` copies `/path/to/source/somefile` to `/path/to/destination/somefile`.

It's very important to preserve the file's modification times. That way you know when a file has last been modified. Your tools also know when a file has been modified. In particular, synchronizing a large directory in which most files haven't been modified is a lot faster if the file times are reliable. Rsync will skip a file quickly if the name, size and modification time are the same on both sides.

You can tell rsync to transfer only files that are newer on the source side by adding the `-u` option (`rsync -au SOURCE DESTINATION`). This limits the risks if the files have also been edited on the destination side: you won't erase the newer version that is on the destination side with the older copy on the source side. However you cannot reliably detect conflicts: if a file has been edited on both sides, whichever version has the most recent modification time will win.

Rsync is a tool to synchronize data in one direction. Do not use it to synchronize in both directions. Instead, use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). Unison maintains a list of file versions each time you run it and will complain loudly if there is ever a conflict (same file edited independently on both sides). As long as there is no conflict (i.e. as long as each file is only modified on one side between synchronizations), Unison will merge the changes on the two sides.

To set up Unison, use the GUI, or create a preferences file called `~/.unison/chef.prf` containing

```
root = /var/chef
root = server.example.com:/var/chef
times = true
```

Run `unison -auto chef` to synchronize the two trees.

Rather than synchronizing files, you should put your files under [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). When you've made changes, commit them to the repository. To deploy your changes, check them out on the server.